# Payment verification when new mobile SDK crashes

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

How can we verify a PayPal payment if the new mobile SDK crashes after the transaction AND before sending the proof of payment to the mobile application?

I can't find ways to solve this issue because we can't pass a CustomID to the SDK.

Thanks

Comment: We're looking in to the custom id question, but we'd also like make sure the SDKs do not crash in the first place. We'd very much appreciate it if you could open issues relating to the crashes at https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues or https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues. Any console output or crashlogs from Apple/Google consoles would be helpful there.

Comment: Will submit issues if I find any. The crash however does not need to be caused by the SDK. It can relate to the OS, memory issues, battery low, etc.